# RabbitMQ: Disable cleartext authentication mechanisms in the AMQP configuration

Tags: rabbitmq

Please support how to disable cleartext authentication in amqp configuration in rabbitmq.
    -bash-4.2$ rabbitmqctl status | grep amqp
          {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","3.6.14"},
          {amqp,5672,"::"},
          {'amqp/ssl',5671,"::"},
    -bash-4.2$

```
 My client uses Python to connect with default port 5672.
 Is there any change can be done in rabbitmq config without disabling the default port??.
```

Comment: -bash-4.2$ rabbitmqctl status | grep amqp
      {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","3.6.14"},
      {amqp,5672,"::"},
      {'amqp/ssl',5671,"::"},
-bash-4.2$